# How to get the id of multiple insert in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am writing a Codeigniter script where I have inserted multiple rows using foreach . I want to get all the last inserted id's.

Here is my code:

```
public function savePickupDataModal($dates, $pickData) {
    foreach ($dates['dates'] as $date) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO pickupManagement (dates, readyhour, readymint, readyformat, latesthour, latestmint, latestformat, approxVal, otherComment) ' .
                    'VALUES("' . $date . '","' . $pickData['readyhour'] . '","' . $pickData['readymint'] . '","' . $pickData['readyformat'] . '","' . $pickData['latesthour'] . '","' . $pickData['latestmint'] . '","' . $pickData['latestformat'] . '","' . $pickData['approxVal'] . '","' . $pickData['otherComment'] . '")';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the date array contains any number of dates like 3, 4 or 5 so the insert query will be executed until the array contains the number of dates.

How do I get all the last inserted records id's?

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are actually performing multiple independent queries, so you can get the last id and push it into an array over and over.

```
$affected_ids = array();
foreach(....

    $query = .....
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        $affected_ids[] = $this->db->insert_id();

}
echo '<pre>', print_r($affected_ids),'</pre>';
```

There doesn't seem to be any need to actually return true or false here.

Comment: this is just returning the last row why ?foreach($affected_ids as $affected_id){
   $fetchQuery = 'SELECT * FROM pickupManagement WHERE pickup_id = "'.$affected_id.'" ';
   $querys = $this->db->query($fetchQuery);
  }
  
  if($querys->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($querys->result() as $results){
     $data[] = $results;
    }
    return $data;
  }

Comment: Place `$affected_ids = array();` before `foreach` loop.